# Script to resize images in a folder doesn't work

Tags: python

I'm a Python Beginner, and I used ChatGPT to write a more ambitious script that would resize all images in a folder to be less than 5MB. When I run it, it doesn't do it, and it send back a keyerror message I don't understand.

This is the script:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

folder_path = r'C:\Users\alexa\Pictures\MovemberShared\MovemberFinalshoot_Copy'
max_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024  

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.JPG') or filename.endswith('.jpeg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
        filepath = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        with Image.open(filepath) as img:
            img.thumbnail((1000, 1000))
            if os.path.getsize(filepath) < max_size:
                continue  
            while os.path.getsize(filepath) >= max_size:
                img.save(filepath, optimize=True, quality=img.info['quality'] - 5)
```

and the error I get back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Pictures\MovemberShared\MovemberFinalshoot_Copy\resizeimages.py", line 15, in <module>
    img.save(filepath, optimize=True, quality=img.info['quality'] - 5)
KeyError: 'quality'
```

How would I go about fixing this? I installed the Pillow library which was necessary and think I did the cmd input right, but here it is just in case attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J0OW.png)

I tried running it with different named variables instead of quality, but don't think that's the right direction as I'm just getting the same error back. I'm hoping it will resize the images in the folder, which also contains the .py I'm using

Comment: apparenlty, you are tyring to access information that does not exist. As a quick fix: remove the whole quality statetment, so just `img.save(filepath, optimize=True)`. If you want to know what information is there in your data: before the line with img.save..., insert a line that says: `print(img.info)` and update your question with the ouput.

Comment: "I used ChatGPT to write a more ambitious script that would resize all images in a folder to be less than 5MB. When I run it, it doesn't do it, and it send back a keyerror message I don't understand"—that's because ChatGPT is __not intelligent__. It has no idea whether the garbage it spits out actually does what you asked it to do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html), `quality` is only a parameter of `save()` & not a property you get when you `open()` an image.

The `quality` parameter looks like a percentage & they say *"Values above 95 should be avoided"*, so you could try something simple like starting at 95 & decrementing by 1 on each iteration...

```py
percent = 95
while os.path.getsize(filepath) >= max_size:
    img.save(filepath, optimize=True, quality=percent)
    percent -= 1
```